# How to query for auto-complete in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is my settings and mappings of the index and doc_type I have used.

```
    es_mapping = {
  "settings": {
      "analysis": {
          "filter": {
              "edgeNGram_filter": {
                  "type": "edgeNGram",
                  "min_gram": 2,
                  "max_gram": 20,
                  "side": "front"
              }
          },
          "analyzer": {
              "edge_nGram_analyzer": {
                  "type": "custom",
                  "tokenizer": "edge_ngram_tokenizer",
                  "filter": [
                      "lowercase",
                      "asciifolding",
                      "edgeNGram_filter"
                  ]
              },
              "whitespace_analyzer": {
                  "type": "custom",
                  "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                  "filter": [
                      "lowercase",
                      "asciifolding"
                  ]
              }
          },
          "tokenizer": {
              "edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
                  "type": "edgeNGram",
                  "min_gram": "2",
                  "max_gram": "5",
                  "token_chars": [
                      "letter",
                      "digit"
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "videos": {
        "properties": {
            "fileName": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "path": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "no"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}

# creating index with the above schema.
es.create_index('media', settings = es_mapping)
```

So, there are only two fields namely **fileName** and **path**, I need to make auto-complete query on **filename**.

I have added all the **ngram-analyzers** and **whitespace analyzer**

The query I make is **match_phrase**

```
"query": {
    "match_phrase": {
        "fileName": {
            "query": "a"
        }
    }
}
```

The above query gives me all the phrases that matches, basically full-text search, but I want something like **alt**, **apple**, **acer** as suggestion, provided theses are there in the index.

How can I alter the query?

### Edit after val suggestion

```
      "settings": {
      "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "autocomplete_filter": {
                "type":     "edge_ngram",
                "min_gram": 1,
                "max_gram": 20
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "autocomplete": {
                "type":      "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "autocomplete_filter"
                ]
            }
          }
      }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "videos": {
        "properties": {
            "fileName": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "autocomplete",
              "search_analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "path": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "no"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, this is the setting and mapping for auto-complete.

And the query is structured as:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "fileName": "a"
        }
    },
    "highlight" : {
        "fields" : {
            "fileName" : {"force_source" : true}
        }
    }
}
```

I use **highlight**, which increases the user interactivity.

Comment: You don't seem to be actually using the analyzers you've defined. You need to either set them as default analyzers or specifically as analyzer or search_analyzer on your fields.

Comment: @val Ya, my bad. Corrected it after your suggestion. Thanks bro!!

Comment: Ok, have you reindexed your data after changing your mapping and adding analyzers? What does the query yield now?

Comment: Does reindexing means **refreshing** after ingesting the data? And ya the query yields all the results the suffixes and also phrases. I will update the query in the answer

Comment: reindexing means wiping your index and rebuilding it in order for the new settings/mappings to kick in

Comment: Ya I have done that @val

Comment: Can you show how do you send your query?

Comment: I don't have the source code right now. Ajax implementation is done implementing the search as you type. So,  for every key event, an Ajax call is sent and populates the search data table. It is fast. But do you recommend any other way to do this search as you type

Comment: Not necessarily, but I'd like to understand why you don't get the expected results

Comment: Val,  after your suggestion I have changed the mapping using search analyzer and now am getting the proper results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the analyzers you've defined. You need to either set them as default analyzers or specifically as `analyzer` or `search_analyzer` on your fields.

Then, you need to wipe your index, recreate it and re-index your data.

Afterwards, you'll get the results you expect.